# MacBook Pro screen muddling up letters

Tags: macbook-pro, screen

I got my MacBook Pro in December so I haven't had it for that long. After a while, on youtube the screen would act up a bit and move around or display transparent grey rectangles or a massive (transparent again) pause button. 
Until one or two days ago. I think it may have started yesterday or it might have been the day before. The letters displayed on the screen are just weird lines and you can't even recognise what the text is supposed to say.

[image]

I'm not sure why this is happening and also I don't know if it's something internally or just something I've installed.

Comment: Does it happen in chrome or everywhere else too? Could be a GPU or screen scaling issue. What resolution are you using it?

Comment: so far it's only happened on chrome and I've got a (2560 x 1600) resolution

Comment: It's a GPU issue. It's happened to me. Use a lower resolution. You'll be fine. Restart if it helps.

Answer (score -1):

It looks like a weird browser extension to me.

Can you go to settings in Chrome, choose Extensions and deactivate all of them?

Comment: He is using chrome.